# angular nested ng-repeat failure

Tags: javascript, angularjs

it's me again :) 
I am still at the very beginning with angularJS and I have just encountered a problematic issue.
I've got an array with some data that I want to be rendered on the page that's why I use ng-repeat but I also need to include another ng-repeat in the previous one. 
I have the general ng-repeat="dialog in dialogWindows" and lower in the DOM ng-repeat="input in dialog.inputs", but the second ngRepeat dousnt work and it reports no errors in the coonsole. can You help me please?

Here is the JS:

```
 var antroApp = angular.module('antroApp', []);

    function dialogWindows($scope){

    $scope.dialogWindows = [
    {id:0, 
    idName:"pigmentation", 
    number:"1", 
    name:"Pigmentation",
    answer1:"Clear complexion",
    answer2:"Semi-swarthy complexion",
    answer3:"Swarthy complexion",
    answer4:"",
    answer5:"",
    answer6:"",
    inputs:[{id:0,a:"a1",answer:"a"},
            {id:1,a:"a2", answer:"b"}],
    }



    ];

    }
    antroApp.controller('antroApp', antroApp);
```

and here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="dialogWindows">
            <div ng-repeat="dialog in dialogWindows">
            <div id="{{dialog.idName}}" class="bold abs">   
                <div class="questionContainer rel">
                    <div class="menu abs">
                        <ul class="menuList">
                            <a href=""><li id="menuStart" class=" unbold">Start</li></a>
                            <a href=""><li id="menuAbout" class=" unbold">About</li></a>
                            <a href=""><li id="menuTech" class=" unbold">Technology</li></a>
                            <a href=""><li id="menuContact" class=" unbold">Contact</li></a>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="questionHeader"><div class="textGradient unbold tgHeaderXY">{{dialog.number}}.{{dialog.name}}</div></div>
                    <div class="empty">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="questionBody">

                    <div ng-repat="input in dialog.inputs">
                    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="sex" value="male">
                    <label for="radio1" class="answer abs {{input.a}}">{{input.answer}}</label>


                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#hairColor" class="nextButton unbold">Next <i class="icon-arrow-right icon-white"></i></a>

            <i class="icon-pencil tgHeaderIcon icon-3x abs"></i>
            </div><!--/pigmentation-->
            </div><!--/ng-repeat-->
            </div><!--/ng-controller-->
```

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just single mistake;

set `<div ng-repeat="input in dialog.inputs">`

instead `<div ng-repat="input in dialog.inputs">`

**As a side note:**

use `<pre>{{input|json}}</pre>` as basic debugger to detect the issue

see <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/571/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. Yes the problem was the naming of ng-repeat. I was working until 4:00AM then I went to sleep and woke up at 9:00AM and back to work that's why I simply overlooked it.

Comment: interesting that it didn't drop compilation erorr

Answer (score 1):

In your nested loop you have to use `ng-repeat`, instead of `ng-repat`. If you would strip off example markup from unnecessary garbage before posting question, you would probably find typo yourself.

Then, you're missing `ng-app="antroApp"` directive in example.

Then, controller is dialogWindows, not antroApp:

```
antroApp.controller('dialogWindows', dialogWindows);
```

Comment: If your answer was: "In your nested loop you have to use ng-repeat, instead of ng-repat. Then, controller is dialogWindows, not antroApp" I would've give you approval but 50% of it was actually accusing me of not knowing the answer though it is the place for the people how are allowed to not know and to ask for help from the people who are more experienced. You failed the test on the puropse on why you are here.

Comment: You put zero effort to ask question properly: Here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist
And if you would have followed those known guidelines for asking question, you would on the way fix your "question". You did not learn anything new from those answers, you just fixed typos in your code. True?

Comment: Follow the link please: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask "How to ask")

Comment: Yes, to change account name when offending people.

Comment: Although stripping off extraneous code is a good idea and good form, Nenad needs to be careful of tone, its hard to interpret it over the internet. 50/50 split.

Answer (score 1):

Missing closing div, typo as per Nenad answer, same naming for App and Controller, same naming for controller and scope variable... ouch my mind hurts, anyways, here is the [result at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/OPopoh/1/edit)

EDIT: (as per minitech request)
this an alternative version, example in jsbin has unnecessary code in question removed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body ng-app="myApp"> <!-- *myApp is antroApp app -->
        <div ng-controller="myCtrl"> <!-- *myCtrl is dialogWindows ctrl  -->
            <div ng-repeat="dialog in data"> <!-- data is dialogWindows scope var -->
                <div class="bold abs">
                    <div class="questionContainer rel">
                        <div class="menu abs">
                            <ul class="menuList"> 
                                <a href=""><li id="menuStart" class=" unbold">Start</li></a>
                                <a href=""><li id="menuAbout" class=" unbold">About</li></a>
                                <a href=""><li id="menuTech" class=" unbold">Technology</li></a>
                                <a href=""><li id="menuContact" class=" unbold">Contact</li></a>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="questionHeader">
                            <div class="textGradient unbold tgHeaderXY">{{dialog.number}}.{{dialog.name}}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="empty">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="questionBody">
                            <div ng-repeat="input in dialog.inputs">
                                <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="sex" value="male" />
                                <label for="radio1" class="answer abs {{input.a}}">{{input.answer}}</label>
                            </div>
                        </div> <a href="#hairColor" class="nextButton unbold">Next <i class="icon-arrow-right icon-white"></i></a>
                        <i class="icon-pencil tgHeaderIcon icon-3x abs"></i>

                    </div><!--/questionContainer--> <!-- *missing div -->
                </div><!--/pigmentation-->
            </div><!--/ng-repeat-->
        </div><!--/ng-controller-->
        <script>
            var App = angular.module('myApp', []); //*myApp is in use now
            App.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', //*myCtrl is in use now 
                function ($scope) {

                    $scope.data = [{
                        id: 0,
                        idName: "pigmentation",
                        number: "1",
                        name: "Pigmentation",
                        answer1: "Clear complexion",
                        answer2: "Semi-swarthy complexion",
                        answer3: "Swarthy complexion",
                        answer4: "",
                        answer5: "",
                        answer6: "",
                        inputs: [{
                                id: 0,
                                a: "a1",
                                answer: "a"
                            }, {
                                id: 1,
                                a: "a2",
                                answer: "b"
                            }]
                    }];

                }]);
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please put the details of your answer inside the… answer :)